# Creating a composite variable from 2 log transformed variables?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, logarithm

I have a data set of 1,100 observations, I have two continuous variables (counts of different things) that were positively skewed, so I first log transformed each of them.
Now I need to make a composite variable, per literature, that measures a construct.

My question, per observation/row, should I now add each of the log transformed numbers together OR create a Z score from each log transformed variable and THEN add the z scores together?

Finally, because I am testing a moderating hypothesis using the composite variable noted above, with a separate categorical variable, I know the composite variable has to be centered before a multiplying with the categorical variable. Does this need for a centered variable change the manner I should add them together? Obviously two Z scores are already mean centered vs. adding two log transforms and subtracting the mean.

Which way is best?

Comment: Why did you log transform them in the first place? OLS regression makes no assumptions about the distribution of the independent variables.

Comment: Peter - I'm using hierarchical regression, they were both positively skewed - I felt like I first ad to address the skewness.

Comment: No, you don't. You have to look at the residuals, not the variables.

Comment: Understood - Should I run the Explore function for Normality plots using each part of the composite variable seperately with the DV or just the summated Zscores from both parts of the composite together with the DV?

Comment: That's a question on which experts differ. I prefer untransformed variables, but other people feel differently

Comment: Thank you so much - I haven't found any literature/text books that provide support either way. I'll try them seperately and then together. I suppose if they result in different answers I'll have a harder decision...

Comment: Peter - having tested the residuals using a PP Plot, my DV and most of my IV's are positively skewed and don't hug the line. After log transforming, they all do much better, but on my DV it has fat tails so the ends fall off below the line. Is there anything else I can do to further enhance the normality of the DV or just run the regression as is?

Comment: Were the residuals normal? You say you tested them  but then you talk about the DV and IVs.

Comment: The middle portion of the DV hugged the line but the left most tail fell below the line and the right most tail dipped/curved below the line then came back up to touch the line.

Comment: One other vexing question-I have a construct IV so I need to join two variables (one a count of people <1K, the other a count of things >1MM) Each raw variable is positively skewed, non-normal PP plots. If I don't standardize each, seems the count of people will get lost in the count of things
So what is the best way to create the new variable
Do I add the raw data then log transform the sum?
Do I create Z scores of each variable and add together?
Do I create Z score of each, add, then log transform? I can't find anything on the site that speaks to this so I would REALLY appreciate your advice

Comment: Take the geometric mean of the two.

Comment: THANK YOU for a this direction - a simply beautiful and elegant solution!